# Styles and Script in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I had created a new module to my orchard application. I'm unable to add styles and script to my views through references. It is showing 404 error to the path even though the path is correct. After reviewing some articles I understood we need to provide the path with Style.Require("stylename") & Script as Script.Require("Scriptname"). While doing it in my views I'm facing the error as "Style" & "Script" not found.[image: My Code Is like this image]

Comment: What is the actual error message you are getting? 404 or an exception? I see you are using `Style.Require` and `Script.Require` - do you have an `IResourceManifestProvider`? Otherwise you may want to use `Style.Include` and `Script.Include` instead.

Comment: "The name script does not exist in the current context." is the error i'm getting. Script tag does not exists so thinking how we get Script.Include  I had already added "IResourceManifestProvider". Even though I use Style.Include we are not even  . This issue we are facing in custom modules,

Comment: Are your styles and scripts in the default folders? Do the folders contain a web.config file?

Comment: Yes, they are in their exact folders(Styles in styles folder & scripts in script folder).For both the folders I had provided the web.config file.

Comment: The problem is not that it can't find your scripts, the problem is that `Script` itself is not accessible in the context where your view is being compiled. Where did you put that view and what `web.config` are there in the same directory or directories above that may have removed access to `Script`? Also, did you ask that exact same question already?

Answer (score 0):

You must check the .net version for this module to be compatible with orchard version, if you using Orchard 1.10, your module must be reference .Net Framework version 4.5.2, to check it go to your project properties and see "Target Framework".