# Script Error in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I'm developing an orchard application. In that I had created a new module under that module I had added my scripts and styles with their web.config files(copied the things as it is from orchard modules. does any thing here to change?). To apply my styles & scripts I created a Manifest file. But after executing I'm facing this Error [image: This Error] and my project structure is as [image: Like This] you can find my entire project structure[image: Project Struccture]

Comment: Your view is somehow not seeing `Script`. Where did you put that view, and is there a `web.config` file in the same directory or a directory above that could have broken this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styles and Script in Orchard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371106/styles-and-script-in-orchard)

Comment: Hai  @BertrandLeRoy , you can find my projects structure in the above. I had placed my project Orchard.HrCompany below the Orchard.Framework.Web.Config file I had provided under root of my project.

Comment: Do I need to change the project location to "Modules" Folder ?

Comment: Well, yes, of course, all modules go under the modules folder.

Comment: Is it mandatory( all modules go under the modules folder ) ? Because we can see that only change is having a within folder(Modules) and without folder(My example orchard.company).

Comment: Almost, you could mess with module loaders, if you had a really, really good reason, but nothing in your scenario seems to indicate that is the case. It's usually a good idea to learn to walk before you learn to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I missed the importing of Orchard.UI.Resources in web.config file of my views directory.
By importing I'm able to add scripts to my views.